# Android - How to get text that user press on it?

Tags: android

I want to get any text (from any app) when user long press on it, in order to, for example translate it.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

goes through the whole process on android developers
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html

Comment: The problem is how to extract the text from other app. For example when user read CNN and press long on one word

Comment: Exactly...  the only thing you can do is after they select copy, they can open your app and you can read the clipboard. But you can't override the long press in another activity

Comment: Have you tried to select some text on CNN for example? you can't do this by long pressing...